# How to use object values and retrieve it in antd form

Tags: reactjs, forms, object, antd

I am using `antd` Form and I am not getting how to use the object values and retrieve them back as in the same order(i.e. after submitting the form I want values as in the `toys`)

[image]

```
const toys = {
    "Car": {
        "color": "Black",
        "available": false
    },
    "Truck": {
        "color": "White",
        "available": true
    },
    "Bus": {
        "color": "Red",
        "available": false
    },
    "Bike": {
        "color": "Blue",
        "available": true
    }
}
```

```js
Object.entries(
  toys
).map(([key, value]) => {
  return (
    <div key={key} className="mb-3">
      <Row type="flex">
        <Col>
          <Input value={key} readOnly />
        </Col>
        <Col>
          <Form.Item className="mb-0">
            {getFieldDecorator(`toys.${value.color}`, {
              initialValue: value.color
            })(<Input />)}
          </Form.Item>
        </Col>
        <Col>
        <Row type="flex">
        <div className="ml-3 mr-3 mt-2">Available</div>
        
          <Form.Item
            className="mr-3 mt-1"
          >
            {getFieldDecorator(`toys.${value.available}`, {
              initialValue: value.available,
              valuePropName: 'checked'
            })(<Switch checkedChildren="Yes" unCheckedChildren="No" />)}
          </Form.Item>
          </Row>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  )
})
```

When we edit and save this form I want the form values below

```
{
    "Car": {
        "color": "Black",
        "available": true
    },
    "Truck": {
        "color": "White",
        "available": true
    },
    "Bus": {
        "color": "Red",
        "available": true
    },
    "Bike": {
        "color": "Blue",
        "available": true
    }
}
```

Right now I am getting values as below and the switch is not working(changing all switches if I toggle one).

```
toys: {
    "Black": "White",
    "false": false,
    "White": "White",
    "true": true,
    "Red": "Red",
    "Blue": "Blue"
}
```

Can Anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to create a custom form item.

```
// to pass values to form the Item need props onChange and value
const CustomObjectCreator = ({ onChange, value }) => {
  const defaultValue = value || {
    color: "",
    available: false
  };
  const [state, setState] = useState(defaultValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    onChange(state);
  }, [state, onChange]);

  const handleChangeSwitch = (available) => {
    setState((oldState) => ({
      ...oldState,
      available
    }));
  };

  const handleChangeInput = (e) => {
    setState((oldState) => ({
      ...oldState,
      color: e.target.value
    }));
  };

  return (
    <Row gutter={32} justify="center">
      <Col span={8}>
        <Input placeholder="color" onChange={handleChangeInput} />
      </Col>
      <Col span={4}>
        <Switch
          checked={state.available}
          checkedChildren="yes"
          unCheckedChildren="no"
          onChange={handleChangeSwitch}
        />
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
};
```

I create a codesandbox example:

[image: Edit ecstatic-leakey-hbu4z]